# Maven install iff changes exist

Tags: java, maven

I was wondering if there is a way to determine whether changes were made to the project and run `mvn install` only in that case. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15405413/4828060) but I am not very interested in incremental build - Ideally I would like the build command to do nothing if no changes were made in the project. Is this possible

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking into time independence of your build.

Currently maven is not built to support that (time stamps in jars etc) so I would suggest using a CI server for this listening to your git repository. For Maven projects Jenkins is a good start.